# Polymorphic DBConnector class exercise

Tags: c#, object-oriented, programming-challenge, polymorphism

### GitHub

[GitHub if it's easier](https://github.com/Webbarrr/MyDbConnector)

---

I'm in the process of doing a training course in C#. I've just gone over covering Polymorphic OOP / composition over inheritance etc...

The latest exercise I completed in the course was to create two base classes, `DBConnector` & `DBCommand` that can be used for any database. The verbatim requirements were as follows -

> To access a database, we need to open a connection to it first and
>   close it once our job is done. Connecting to a database depends on the
>   type of the target database and the database management system (DBMS).
>   For example, connecting to a SQL Server database is different from
>   connecting to an Oracle database. But both these connections have a
>   few things in common:
>   - They have a connection string
>   - They can be opened
>   - They can be closed
>   - They may have a timeout attribute (so if the
>   connection could not be opened within the timeout, an exception will
>   be thrown).
>
> Your job is to represent these commonalities in a base
>   class called `DbConnection`. This class should have two properties:
>   - `ConnectionString` : `string`
>   - `Timeout` : `TimeSpan`
>   `DbConnection` will not be in a valid state if it doesn’t have a connection string. So you need
>   to pass a connection string in the constructor of this class. Also,
>   take into account the scenarios where null or an empty string is sent
>   as the connection string. Make sure to throw an exception to guarantee
>   that your class will always be in a valid state. Our DbConnection
>   should also have two methods for opening and closing a connection. We
>   don’t know how to open or close a connection in a DbConnection and
>   this should be left to the classes that derive from DbConnection.
>   These classes (e.g. SqlConnection or OracleConnection) will provide the
>   actual implementation. So you need to declare these methods as
>   abstract. Derive two classes SqlConnection and OracleConnection from
>   DbConnection and provide a simple implementation of opening and
>   closing connections using Console.WriteLine(). In the real-world, SQL
>   Server provides an API for opening or closing a connection to a
>   database. But for this exercise, we don’t need to worry about it.

And for the DBCommand -

> Now that we have the concept of a DbConnection, let’s work out how to
>   represent a DbCommand. Design a class called DbCommand for executing
>   an instruction against the database. A DbCommand cannot be in a valid
>   state without having a connection. So in the constructor of this
>   class, pass a DbConnection. Don’t forget to cater for the null. Each
>   DbCommand should also have the instruction to be sent to the database.
>   In case of SQL Server, this instruction is expressed in T-SQL
>   language. Use a string to represent this instruction. Again, a command
>   cannot be in a valid state without this instruction. So make sure to
>   receive it in the constructor and cater for the null reference or an
>   empty string. Each command should be executable. So we need to create
>   a method called Execute(). In this method, we need a simple
>   implementation as follows: Open the connectionRun the instruction
>   Close the connectionNote that here, inside the DbCommand, we have a
>   reference to DbConnection. Depending on the type of DbConnection sent
>   at runtime, opening and closing a connection will be different. For
>   example, if we initialize this DbCommand with a SqlConnection, we will
>   open and close a connection to a Sql Server database. This is
>   polymorphism. Interestingly, DbCommand doesn’t care about how a
>   connection is opened or closed. It’s not the responsibility of the
>   DbCommand. All it cares about is to send an instruction to a database.
>   For running the instruction, simply output it to the Console. In the
>   real-world, SQL Server (or any other DBMS) provides an API for running
>   an instruction against the database. We don’t need to worry about it
>   for this exercise. In the main method, initialize a DbCommand with
>   some string as the instruction and a SqlConnection. Execute the
>   command and see the result on the console. Then, swap the SqlConnection
>   with an OracleConnection and see polymorphism in action.

This is the first exercise in the course I've struggled with & would appreciate a more learned eye to have a look at it. I don't feel that I've done particularly well in this exercise. As I feel the need to have called `base.Open();` inside both derived classes is a bit of a bad design, but I'm not 100% sure how else I could go about it.

These are my base classes -

```
public class DBConnection
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }

    public DBConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection String is required.");

        this._connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public virtual void Open()
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;

        // connection code would go here...

        var endTime = DateTime.Now;

        CheckTimeout(startTime, endTime);
    }

    public virtual void Close()
    {
    }

    private void CheckTimeout(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        if (endTime - startTime >= this.Timeout)
            throw new TimeoutException("The connection timed out...");
    }
}


public class DBCommand
{
    private readonly DBConnection _dBConnection;
    private readonly string _sql;

    public DBCommand(DBConnection dBConnection, string sql)
    {
        _dBConnection = dBConnection ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("DBConnection required.");
        this._sql = sql ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("sql required.");
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _dBConnection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine($"Executing: {_sql}");
        _dBConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

And here are my derived classes -

```
public class SqlConnection : DBConnection 
{
    public SqlConnection(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        base.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing connection to SQL Server...");
    }

    public override void Open()
    {
        base.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opening connection to SQL Server...");
        Console.WriteLine($"Timeout is set to {base.Timeout}");
    }
}

public class OracleConnection : DBConnection
{
    public OracleConnection(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing connection to Oracle...");
    }

    public override void Open()
    {
        base.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opening connection to Oracle...");
        Console.WriteLine($"Oracle has no timeout");
    }
}
```

And finally my test code -

```
    static void UsingDbCommand()
    {
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("My.SQL.ConnectionString");
        var sqlCommand = new DBCommand(sqlConnection, "DROP TABLE tblUsers -- On SQL Server");
        sqlCommand.Execute();

        var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection("My.Oracle.ConnectionString");
        var oracleCommand = new DBCommand(oracleConnection, "DROP TABLE tblUsers -- On Oracle");
        oracleCommand.Execute();

        try
        {
            var fakeSQLConnection = new SqlConnection("fasdf");
            var fakeSQLCommand = new DBCommand(fakeSQLConnection, null);
            fakeSQLCommand.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how this could get a bit confusing. The way the requirements are phrased make it bit more difficult. Maybe it was written in an attempt to not give an obvious solution. But, it did take more effort to follow at least for me.

I'm making the assumption that you're only supposed to use inheritance for this step, and interfaces are not necessary.

Let's start with **DbConnection**, which need:

- ConnectionString property
- Timeout property
- Open abstract method
- Close abstract method

```
public class DBConnection
{
[...]
```

The class needs to be abstract if we're going to use abstract methods.

```
[...]
    private readonly string _connectionString;
[...]
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to access connection string from classes inheriting `DBConnection` see [Access Levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)

```
[...]
    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }
[...]
```

No problem with the above, but I would recommend at least making it virtual so that the classes inheriting from this abstraction can control the accessibility if requirements change.

```
[...]
    public virtual void Open()
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;

        // connection code would go here...

        var endTime = DateTime.Now;

        CheckTimeout(startTime, endTime);
    }

    public virtual void Close()
    {
    }

    private void CheckTimeout(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        if (endTime - startTime >= this.Timeout)
            throw new TimeoutException("The connection timed out...");
    }
}
[...]
```

1. On the above, I notice that neither **Open** or **Close** methods are abstract
2. Neither method should have any code in the DBConnection. SqlServer and OracleDatabase will likely use different APIs so the code in the abstraction will likely always get overwritten and not used. Even if you do try and force its use, you would be calling open twice in a way. And, the part that interacts with the API will end up having nothing to do with the start time/endtime variables.
3. About this `CheckTimeout` it's not really in the requirement. So I invoke [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Problem is that, it will be very difficult to deal with that at the Base Class since we are given a hint that we **may** need to use it during implementation.

Once you take care of the DBConnection class you shouldn't need to call `base.Open()` in the implementations. And, you shouldn't need to set timeout in the constructor, nor write timeout line in the implementation open method.

The only other issue that I see with the code is in the **DBCommand** constructor:

```
[...]
        this._sql = sql ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("sql required.");
[...]
```

The requirement states:

> [...] So make sure to receive it in the constructor and cater for the null reference or an empty string.

This may deal with a null value. But, it will not catch string.Empty or whitespace strings. You should probably use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() like you did in SqlConnection.

Actually I think this may be the first time I've seen the `??` operator to throw. That's not saying, it's good or bad, I just never thought of it. Though, it does make the line longer, which depending on formatting rules can be a problem. Than again, it could be formatted slightly different to help. Maybe someone else has a better opinion on that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thanks for your answer. Your first paragraph pretty much sums up my experience with this exercise. I was very confused about how I was supposed to go about doing some of the things based on the requirements.

Edit: forgot I had to do shift line break.

I've taken your points on board & made a few extra amendments of my own, for example on your point around `this._sql = sql ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("sql required.");` I did some test cases to check & they seemed to work, although I think I should stick to a consistent approach. I've updated GitHub

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Yeah, I'm not sure "cater" is a good word to use when asking to handle nulls.
I did do a quick check. Since the new code is not here I added [issue1](https://github.com/Webbarrr/MyDbConnector/issues/1) and [issue2](https://github.com/Webbarrr/MyDbConnector/issues/2) on your github project.

Comment: I would also like to suggest getting familiar with unit testing frameworks. I like [xunit](https://xunit.net/) or [nunit](https://nunit.org/). It's a bit difficult at first, but it becomes increasingly simple the more you use it. Visually checking outputs relies on your concentration and effort every time you run the test as well as the assumptions and effort you made when you wrote it. While a unit test relies on the assumptions and writing effort. So you reduce steps, efforts and the chance of visually missing something.